# Why does JS eval() return only the value of an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, eval

If I do this:

```
var x = eval('{a:"b"});
console.log(x); // -> "b"
```

all I get is the value in the object ("b"), not the key/property, or the whole object itself, which is weird.

but when I do this:

```
var x = eval('(function self(){return {a:"b"}})()');
console.log('x'); //  -> {a:'b'}
```

now it seems to give me what I would expect, the whole object. But why is this? Why do I need to wrap it in a (self-executing) function?

I am thinking of using eval to create some objects from strings, but need to know better how this works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `{a:"b"}` statement as-is represents the following:

1. A code [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) delimited by `{ ... }`
2. A [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) `a:`
3. A string literal `"b"`

The latter being the only expression produces the result.

And the same in the AST explorer: [https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/909bebf...](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/909bebff700dce09c71e15f67787a503/6ccdd7cdf4d77378e54c206973e87a829c181704)

To return an object you need to turn it into an expression first, like: wrap it in parentheses: `eval('({a:"b"})')`

But the whole idea of "I am thinking of using eval to create some objects from strings" sounds suspicious.

Comment: I guess the JS spec defines {} as a "code block" but this is rarely seen in regular JS code - what does a "code block" look like? Usually a code block is only in the context of a function.

Comment: @AlexanderMills you see blocks all the time `if (true) { ... }` - here is a code block. A lot of stuff accepts a single statement as an "operand", that's where a block acts as a "container" for multiple statements.

Comment: @AlexanderMills: It's not code blocks that are rare, you use code blocks in if, for, while etc. It's labels that are rare and almost never used